# How to create an alias for a private inner class (using XStream)?

Tags: java, alias, xstream

I'm creating aliases for long class names... It works perfectly fine, but one of the serialized classes is a private inner class. I can't think of a way to create an alias for it other than making it public. I don't like this solution, because it should not be public in the first place. But since making an alias for it will make it possible to change package and class names without having to modify XML files (because the first tag is the fully qualified class name).

This is how I create aliases:

```
xstreamInstance.alias("ClassAlias", OuterClass.InnerClassToAlias.class);
```

That's why I need public access to that inner class.

So, if anyone knows a trick to alias a private inner class, I would really like to hear about it.

Comment: I've learned that XStream has two modes: Pure Java and Enhanced. In Enhanced mode, XStream seams to be able to reach a lot more private/inner/static/etc. members than in Pure Java mode. But I believe that, in my case, I cannot assume that all JVMs that will be running my code will be supported by XStream Enhanced mode (it's JVM dependent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class like the following and pass your reference to the `xstreamInstance` to the `alias` method.

```
public class Parent {
    public void alias(XStream x) {
        x.alias("Kiddie", Parent.Child.class);
    }

    private class Child {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea. Thank you. So I have the choice between making the class public or adding a small method... The small method is very interesting since it doesn't allow things that shouldn't be possible (like to instantiate that inner class from elsewhere).

Comment: This will work if the private class is under your control. How could one define an alias for a private class that is not under one's controll, like java.util.Arrays$ArrayList? Any ideas?

Comment: To answer my own question: get an instance of the class in question and use getClass() on the instance. The idea comes from [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.xstream.user/5930)

Answer (score 0):

How about using annotations for the alias?

```
public class Parent {
    @XStreamAlias("kiddie")
    private class Child {

    }
}
```

Edit: Alas, parsing of annotations of nested classes is not supported by XStream when asking to get the parent class parsed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Only difference with the example above is that my inner class is static (nested class).

Comment: I looked into the XStream code and indeed it will not parse nested classes implicitly.

Comment: Annotations of inner classes are correctly parsed in Auto-Detect mode, but it has a number of implications. See http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html#AutoDetect